# Calling Function on onClick in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, addeventlistener

In my Component definition in React, I am appending an `eventListener` like this:

```
/* events.js */
export function mouseyDown( event ) {
    console.log( event.target );
}

/* main.js */
import mouseyDown from '../controllers/events.js';
const Topbar = React.createClass ({
    callMouseyDown : function( event ) {
        console.log( event.target );
        mouseyDown(); // actually need to pass event to this method too
    },
    render : function() {
        return (
            <div className="tbIcon" data-action="shareSocial" onClick={ this.callMouseyDown}>G</div>
    )}
});
```

However, React is giving me this error:

> _EventController2.default is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mousedown is not property of created object but function which you have imported. Therefore you need to omit `this` keyword:

```
onClick={mouseyDown}
```

Moreover you need to export your function as default:

```
export default function mouseyDown( event ) {
    console.log( event.target );
}
// ...
import mouseyDown from '../controllers/events.js';
```

or use named import:

```
export function mouseyDown( event ) {
    console.log( event.target );
}
// ...
import {mouseyDown} from '../controllers/events.js';
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesnt seem to work. I get no error, nothing. Ive renamed the onClick function for clarity.

Comment: You are a genius of the highest order. Thank you.